# Error de sintaxis al importar en el shell

Tags: python, django, shell, python-import

Cuando trato de importar a traves del shell (`python manage.py shell`) y y cuando escribo en el shell - `from and.models import Post`- me lanza un error de sintaxis alegando que es invalido

```
from django.db import models

from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    autor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    texto = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(
    default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
    blank = True, null = False)

def published(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.titulo
```

Esta es mi estructura de carpetas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el repo se llama `and`??, podrias agregar una foto con la estructura de tus carpetas

Comment: Listo amigo ya la he subido

Comment: Tu problema es al importar en el shell, no es al ejecutar desde el ide.?

Comment: Me parece muy extraño, has intentado cambiarle el nombre a la carpeta and ?

Comment: Ya le he cambiado el and por otras opciones y sigue dandome ese error, y si el problema es al momento de trabajar con el shell, no he seguido adelante con el tutorial por este error que me sale, no se si simplemente puedo obviarlo y no pasara nada o si afectara algo :/

Comment: la palabra `and` es una palabra reservada de python por ello no funciona como te  dijeron en comentarios anteriores, intenta cambiar el nombre de la carpeta, agregar el nombre nuevo de la carpeta al `settings.py` en `INSTALLED_APPS` y deberia funcionar, te recomiendo ejecutar de nuevo los comandos `migrate` esto es opcional

Comment: ahora si te quieres evitar el error que no lo recomiendo puedes hacer algo como `andMudule = __import__("and")` y luego puedes acceder a Post algo como `andMudule.models.Post` <sub> aunque puede cambiar si lo ve abulafia</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como ya te han dicho, no es buena idea nombrar un módulo con el nombre de una palabra reservada python. Ten en cuenta que cuando haces `import and`, si python te dejara, `and` pasaría a ser un espacio de nombres (el módulo), sobreescribiendo el significado que tuviera antes en python.

En el caso particular de `and` no te deja por ser palabra reservada (lo mismo que no puedes tener un módulo llamado `None`, o `if`, o `while`, o `class`, ...). Otros identificadores del lenguaje no son palabras reservadas y por tanto sí que te dejaría tener módulos así llamados (por ejemplo puedes tener un módulo llamado `print`, o `str`, o `int`, o `type`, entre otros), y seguiría siendo pésima idea porque perderías el significado original de esos identificadores.

No obstante, sólo como curiosidad circense (no lo intenten en sus casas), las dos siguientes líneas te darían el mismo resultado que el hipotético `from and.model import Post`, si hubieras podido ejecutar este último:

```
import importlib
Post = importlib.import_module("and.model").Post
```

Insisto, lo correcto es cambiar de nombre ese módulo.

### Extra

La lista de palabras reservadas puedes obtenerla con:

```
>>> import keyword
>>> keyword.kwlist
['False', 'None', 'True', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 
'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 
'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'nonlocal', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'raise', 
'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

Y la lista de otros identificadores del lenguaje que no están reservados, pero tampoco interesa andar cambiando se puede obtener con:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> dir(builtins)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 
'BlockingIOError', 'BrokenPipeError', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 
'ChildProcessError', 'ConnectionAbortedError', 'ConnectionError', 
'ConnectionRefusedError', 'ConnectionResetError', 'DeprecationWarning', 
'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 
'FileExistsError', 'FileNotFoundError', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 
'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 
'IndexError', 'InterruptedError', 'IsADirectoryError', 'KeyError', 
'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'ModuleNotFoundError', 
'NameError', 'None', 'NotADirectoryError', 'NotImplemented', 
'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 
'PermissionError', 'ProcessLookupError', 'RecursionError', 'ReferenceError', 
'ResourceWarning', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StopAsyncIteration', 
'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 
'TabError', 'TimeoutError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 
'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 
'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 
'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__build_class__', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__',
 '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 
'ascii', 'bin', 'bool', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 
'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 
'enumerate', 'eval', 'exec', 'exit', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 
'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 
'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'map', 
'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 
'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 
'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 
'type', 'vars', 'zip']
```

Comment: completando la pregunta, cada vez que necesite algún archivo del modulo `and` va a tener que ejecutar el comando `import importlib ....` volviendo el codigo mas complejo que el solo cambiar el nombre de la carpeta